# Routes with question marks in routing table

Tags: linux, ip, routes

When I do

```
ip route show table all
```

I see some routes with question marks in them as below.

`multicast ???/32 from ???/32 table default proto none iif eth0`

They appear to be multicast routes. I don't have any idea how they end up having these funny question marks. Actually I was even wondering if multicast routes shall be added to the routing table at all.

Anyone who could put some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`???`" is output when the address family of the route entry matched none of the AFs iproute knows how to print (`AF_INET`, `AF_INET6`, `AF_IPX`, `AF_DECNET`).

Comment: Thanks jørgensen. Does a multicast route match one of these AFs?

Comment: It depends on the particular route entry that was entered into system.